# Terminating app due to uncaught exception Cannot Install Constraint, reason: No common superview between views

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

I am trying to programmatically create a button and apply constraints with SnapKit. Everything works fine, but when i apply constraint as `make.center.equalTo(self.view)`
it crashes giving me this message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception Cannot Install Constraint, reason: No common superview between views". Here is my code for creating button:

```
    func createButton() {
    let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    button.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalTo(200)
        make.height.equalTo(70)
        make.center.equalTo(self.view)
    }

    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The button must be inside a view before you can add constraints.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. It was a silly mistake of mine)